# Cron.php not working using cronjob setting from Cpanel and no confirmation mail send to customer in magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: php, cron

I just set cron job using cpanel of my site,

according to that cron.php runs in every 5 mins.

But it's not.
It is working whenever  I execute cron.php directly from browser.

**Here is the code of my cron.php :**

```
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
require 'app/bootstrap.php';
require 'app/Mage.php';
if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
    echo "Application is not installed yet, please complete install wizard first.";
   exit;
}
// Only for urls
// Don't remove this
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);
umask(0);
$disabledFuncs = explode(',', ini_get('disable_functions'));
$isShellDisabled = is_array($disabledFuncs) ? in_array('shell_exec', $disabledFuncs) : true;
$isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;
$isShellDisabled = true;
try {
    if (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) {
        $options = getopt('m::');
        if (isset($options['m'])) {
            if ($options['m'] == 'always') {
                 $cronMode = 'always';
            } elseif ($options['m'] == 'default') {
                 $cronMode = 'default';
            } else {
                 Mage::throwException('Unrecognized cron mode was defined');
             }
        } else if (!$isShellDisabled) {
            $fileName = escapeshellarg(basename(__FILE__));
            $cronPath = escapeshellarg(dirname(__FILE__) . '/cron.sh');

            shell_exec(escapeshellcmd("/bin/sh $cronPath $fileName -mdefault 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &"));
            shell_exec(escapeshellcmd("/bin/sh $cronPath $fileName -malways 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &"));
            exit;
        }
    }
    Mage::getConfig()->init()->loadEventObservers('crontab');
    Mage::app()->addEventArea('crontab');
    if ($isShellDisabled) {
        Mage::dispatchEvent('always');
        Mage::dispatchEvent('default');
    } else {
        Mage::dispatchEvent($cronMode);
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage:: printException($e); //Please remove space after Mage:: p
    exit(1);
}
```

[image]

please check and let me know why its not working or call automatically, no mail send to customers when they purchase any product.

Comment: Change command to php -q /home1/shoppjb2/public_html/cron.php

Comment: I already try this, but not working for me no mail received or no error in exception file.

Comment: @Marius When i tried this **php /home1/shoppjb2/public_html/cron.php** I have got an email each time when cron executed i.e. **Status: 500 Internal Server Error
Content-type: text/html**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue Solved** 
I just changed **php /home1/user_name/public_html/cron.php** to /**usr/php/54/usr/bin/php -q /home1/user_name/public_html/cron.php**. Here **54** is my **hostserver php version**.

Answer (score 0):

**PHP command examples:**

*General example:*
/usr/local/bin/php /home/foohe82gflhl/public_html/path/to/cron/script

*Domain-specific example:*
/usr/local/bin/ea-php56 /home/foohe82gflhl/domain_path/path/to/cron/script

**My Specific Working Solution:**

/usr/local/bin/php /home/foohe82gflhl/public_html/balrajeshwar/get99acerslead.php

**Description:**
**php path** *your specific folder location where php file exist*